# Oracle SQL Query - Join when using MAX() function

Tags: sql, oracle

Good afternoon,

I am trying to put together a query that will select data from 2 tables when using the MAX() function to return the user's most recent login time.

The tables are as follows:

USERS:

```
USERNAME          CREATED
JOHNSMITH         01/01/2015
MATTTYLER         12/12/2013
DAVIDCROSS        09/07/2014
SARAHTHOMPSON     02/05/2015
```

SESSIONS:

```
USERNAME          ACTION          TIMESTAMP
JOHNSMITH         LOGOUT          13/09/2015 10:00:00
MATTTYLER         LOGOUT          13/09/2015 05:00:00
JOHNSMITH         LOGIN           12/09/2015 15:00:00
MATTTYLER         LOGIN           12/09/2015 11:00:00
JOHNSMITH         LOGOUT          12/09/2915 12:00:00
JOHNSMITH         LOGIN           12/09/2015 05:00:00
```

Result:

```
USERNAME          CREATED          TIMESTAMP (as LASTLOGIN)
JOHNSMITH         01/01/2015       12/09/15 15:00:00
MATTTYLER         12/12/2013       12/09/15 11:00:00
DAVIDCROSS        09/07/2014       NULL
SARAHTHOMPSON     02/05/2015       NULL
```

If MAX() is not the most appropriate function to select the most recent login time, please feel free to suggest a better approach. If possible, can you please demonstrate how to achieve this using both the SQL-89 and SQL-92 joins?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` to also get users never logged in. `GROUP BY` with `MAX` to get each user's latest `TIMESTAMP`.

```
select u.username, u.created, max(s."TIMESTAMP")
from users u
  left join sessions s on u.username = s.username
group by u.username, u.created
```

SQL-92 (join used. `Timestamp` is a reserved word in SQL-92, that's why it's delimited as `"TIMESTAMP"`.

SQL-89 (aka SQL 1), if no left join available, do a correlated sub-query instead:

```
select u.username, u.created,
       (select max("TIMESTAMP") from sessions s
        where u.username = s.username)
from users u
```

(Didn't Oracle have `+=` or `=+` for left join, when old-style join syntax is used?)

Comment: Thanks jarlh, you've been a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is via analytic functions:

```
select username,
       created,
       "TIMESTAMP"
  from (select u.*,
               s."TIMESTAMP",
               row_number() over( partition by u.username
                                  order by s."TIMESTAMP" desc ) as rnk
          from users u
          left join sessions s
            on u.username = s.username)
 where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `group by` with `max` is fine when you are looking only at a few fields, but if you wanted, say, many fields from Users and/or Sessions along with just the last login date added, the `group by` list could be really long. Here is an alternate method that doesn't use grouping.

What this does is take each row from Users and join it with the Session row with the login time from the one correlated row from Sessions with the latest login time.

```
select  u.*, s.Timestamp "Last Login"
from    Users u
left join Sessions  s
    on  s.Username  = u.Username
    and s.Action    = 'login'
    and s.Timestamp =(
        select  Max( timestamp )
        from    Sessions 
        where   UserName  = s.Username
            and Action    = s.Action );
```

The natural key of Sessions is (Username, Timestamp) but if there is an index on (UserName, Action, Timestamp), the query above will run impressively fast even though it has a subquery.

Notice, btw, that you're looking for the lastest *login* timestamp, not just the latest timestamp.

However, the query above, while it will work on most DBMSs, does not work with Oracle. It has a "feature" that does not allow subqueries in outer joins. This is inconvenient but not insurmountable. Old Oracle hands probably already know what to do, but here it is for the everyone else.

We have to move the subquery from the join criteria to the filter criteria. Normally, this is just a matter of cutting and pasting, or in this case, just change the final `and` to `where`:

```
select  u.*, s.Timestamp "Last Login"
from    Users u
left join Sessions  s
    on  s.Username  = u.Username
    and s.Action    = 'login'
where   s.Timestamp =(
        select  Max( timestamp )
        from    Sessions 
        where   UserName  = s.Username
            and Action    = s.Action );
```

However, when you move some or all of the join criteria of an outer join to the filtering clause, you now filter out the results where the Sessions data is null -- thus making the result set the same as an inner join. Many mistakenly think the outer join is actually converted to an inner join, but it's just the output is filtered so it looks like an inner join.

This is also easily fixed. Just insert an explicit filter for those null results:

```
select  u.*, s.Timestamp "Last Login"
from    Users u
left join Sessions  s
    on  s.Username  = u.Username
    and s.Action    = 'login'
where   s.Username is null
    or  s.Timestamp =(
        select  Max( timestamp )
        from    Sessions 
        where   UserName  = s.Username
            and Action    = s.Action );
```

Ok, because this is Oracle, a fairly simple answer is a little more complicated. But it's good to know alternate methods.

And no, I don't know how to do this using the old join syntax. I'm sure there's a way, I just moved over as soon as the new syntax hit and never went back. So that's been a looooooooong time for me.